# ADB debugging: Mobile is showing offline

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, adb

I installed Android studio after finishing my app . 
I am trying to run my app but in my debugging process my mobile is showing offline.not only for mobile i tried whit different mobile also then also it showing like that only help me.

Comment: sometimes it happens because of defective USB cables.....Try a different one..

Comment: try to use a new cable :)

Answer (score 0):

just unplug and then plug your USB cable. or else try with some other cable.
if it doesnot work then reboot your device.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have enabled **USB Debugging** on *Developer options* of your phone.

This can be done by turning **Settings -> Developer options > Usb debugging** option on.

http://blog.syncios.com/enable-developer-optionsusb-debugging-mode-on-devices-with-android-4-2-jelly-bean/

Comment: You might want to reboot your Device and your PC and try again. Sometimes, reboot just solves them all. I had a lot of problems like this, most of the time, I just reboot or reinstall to solve it.

Comment: that also i did. my mobile is working in another system it's not working in my system only

Comment: Then we know that there is a high chance that your PC has problem. Have you tried adb remount to check if it's online?  Or does SD Card of your phone comes up on your explorer?

Comment: @chinna please update your system driver connect your phone